# The meaning of "underwritten" in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of **underwritten** in this sentence

> The actor plays a man who uses his disorder to balance books for criminals in a film that struggles to balance derivative action and **underwritten** romance

I searched dictionary for **underwrite** but none of the meanings makes sense when it's used as an adjective before romance

Comment: It's a pun for what the writer believes to have been a poorly-developed romance in a film about underwriting.

Answer (score 13):

It's a joke.

The two words *derivative* and *underwrite* have one pair of meanings in the financial context which is the movie's setting, but very different meanings in critical contexts.

The headline writer exploits this contrast to describe two of the reviewer's central complaints: a) that the movie's plot and characterization are entirely formulaic—*derivative* and b) that the movie's romantic subplot is perfunctory—*underwritten*.

Comment: I might even venture to say that it's a pun.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang You and StoneyB are really smart and I see great futures for both of you

Comment: @Kevin Glad you're so bullish!

Comment: Agreed. Bear in mind that this use of "underwritten" in the context of a critical review is not common or standard to my knowledge (hence it not appearing in dictionaries); it's simple extrapolation from the "under-" prefix and the word "written", so it can be deduced to mean that not enough effort was put into writing it. It only really makes sense in the context of being a pun ;)

Comment: @StoneyB I'm starting to lose interest in these puns.

Comment: @Sabre The feeling's mutual.